# count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in

Tags: php

I'm getting this warning on my website, im just getting the information is it IP available or not, it's work, its says it's unavailable but it shows an warning also about code, I searched about it, but none of those answers didn't help me. So the code is working, just want to get off this warning. Php 7.x doesn't support syntax like this? The problem is in if (count($test)==1).

```
$printers = file("printers.txt"); //input txt file with IP addresses in chosen order
    $number_of_printers = count ($printers);
    for ( $i = 0 ; $i < $number_of_printers ; $i++)
    {
    $ip=str_replace("\r\n","",$printers[$i]);
    $ip=str_replace("\r","",$ip);
    $ip=str_replace("\n","",$ip);
    $test=@get_headers("http://$ip");
    if (count($test)==1){

        //do stuff here
        echo "<div class='printerwrapper'<div class='location'>$ip is unavailable</div></div>";
        continue;
    }
```

Comment: Would assume `$printers` is `false`. Check with [`empty`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php).

Comment: `$test` most likely isn't an array. What do you get if you `var_dump($test)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When [`get_headers()`](https://php.net/get_headers) fails it returns `false` and `count(false)` triggers that warning [since PHP/7.2](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration72.incompatible.php#migration72.incompatible.warn-on-non-countable-types) ([demo](https://3v4l.org/SNvY7)). The rationale is that counting a boolean false and getting `1` doesn't make much sense.

Perhaps you just want this:

```
if (!$test) {
    //do stuff here
    echo "<div class='printerwrapper'<div class='location'>$ip is unavailable</div></div>";
    continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**get_headers($ip)**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-headers.php) provides you an array if the `$ip` is exist, otherwise it returns FALSE. So you should check the return value of `get_headers()` weather it is an array or not. An example:

```
$headerInfo = @get_headers("http://127.0.0.1");

if (is_array($headerInfo) && count($headerInfo)) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do others
}
```

**Note**: PHP [**count**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php) demands the first argument an array or countable object.

Comment: this code just remove the warning, but i had a lot of security warning about no respond from IP's that isn't working.